# How to set a new field with a referenced value from another collection

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, I have a document as the following:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("sdsfsdgsfdgfghdhg454"),
    "some_field": {
                      "$ref": "SomeOtherCollection",
                       "$id": ObjectId("asdfgeghhnjgfgf")
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

I need to create a new field that stores the String value of reference's "$id" field, like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("sdsfsdgsfdgfghdhg454"),
    "some_field": {
                      "$ref": "SomeOtherCollection",
                       "$id": ObjectId("asdfgeghhnjgfgf")
    },
    "new_field": "asdfgeghhnjgfgf"
}
```

Is there a way in MongoDB to do this? the version of MongoDB that I'm using is 3.6.20.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards.

Comment: Why you field names contain $ sign? It is not recommended by mongodb.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/

Comment: even for DBRef?